# C# WebRequest POST method on HTTPS url is automatically using the http url

Tags: c#, ssl, post, webrequest

I'm writing a program in C# using the WebRequest class and I want to send some data on an HTTPS url.for the GET method everything is fine but when I use the POST method it automatically uses the HTTP instead of HTTPS. I used HTTPDebuggerPro to find out what url the request is going to.

Another weird thing is when I use the WebClient class its not working but when I open the HttpDebuggerPro application and use the Decrypt SSL option it works just fine.here is a example of a code that uses the http url for me instead of https

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.example.com/a.php");
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = "someData";
byte[] postDataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

I expect this code to send the request to the https url but it sends it to the http url.

Comment: `var request = WebRequest.Create("Uri or string with schema")`. See at run-time what type is `request`. It won't be `WebRequest`. See also `WebRequest.CreateHttp()`. + `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` supposes that you URL-Encode the content. See `WebUtility.UrlEncode()` (or `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`).

Comment: I'm sorry but how is this is related to the problem I'm having?

Comment: `WebRequest` is not `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: I already edited the tag before you sent the first comment but thank you.

Comment: It's not about the Question's Tags, it's about your code. The first line of it, to be specific.

Comment: I can't see your point there is no HttpWebRequest in it.can you be more specific? also `var request = WebRequest.Create()` returns WebRequest

Comment: `var request = WebRequest.Create([Uri or string with schema])` does **not** return `WebRequest`. I told you to check this out at run-time. You might also want to take a look at the Docs about that method and what it does.

Comment: oh ok i can see that now yes you are completely right.but how is this related to my problem?

Comment: Well, you'll have to test this out. Same thing goes for `request.GetResponse();`. You have to cast it to `HttpWebResponse`. Note the `Http` prefix, on both the actual worker classes. `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` are your guys. They're not the same thing. Also, add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` on top of everything.

Comment: Actually, I tried your code sample and it sends the web request in https correctly.

Comment: thank you @Youssef13. the thing is on one computer it does work correctly and in another it does not and I have not figured out what the problem is yet.